# Rails 6 Jquery Error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).transition is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm getting the error:

```
application.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).transition is not a function
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (application.js:31)
at HTMLElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4588)
at HTMLElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4408)
```

Here is my application.js file from Rails 6.

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
require("jquery")
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
//= require semantic-ui
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)




$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.message .close')
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("button")
    $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  })
;
})
```

That console log does fire, so everything up to that line appear to be working.  Any ideas what could cause this?

The code that I got was directly from the Semantic UI website.

Comment: You've not included semanticUI in the page, so the `transition()` method is not available.

Comment: Like using require("semantic-ui")?

Comment: You are using sprockets `require` statements within a `webpack` file, this are two different things. Check this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKOq5_2qj54